# cmd process not exiting

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I was running the following code to execute commands from vb.net app.

```
    Dim CMDServer As Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    Dim CMDReply As Diagnostics.Process
    CMDServer = New Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    CMDServer.WorkingDirectory = "C:/"
    CMDServer.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    CMDServer.UseShellExecute = False
    CMDServer.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    CMDServer.RedirectStandardError = True
    CMDServer.CreateNoWindow = True
    CMDServer.Arguments = "/C " + command
    CMDReply = Process.Start(CMDServer)
    MsgBox("START")
    Dim Reply As String = ""
    If Not CMDReply.HasExited Then
        CMDReply.WaitForExit()
    End If
    MsgBox("EXIT")
    Try
        Dim ext = CMDReply.ExitCode
        Reply = CMDReply.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
        MsgBox(ext.ToString + "   " + Reply)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

it works fine for almost all commands, but when the `command="help"` the program stucks on `CMDReply.WaitForExit()`. Can anyone explain what may be the problem here?

Comment: Standard deadlock.  Read the output first and *then* wait for exit.  The program cannot exit until you've read *all* of its output.  The code you have can only work if there's little output that fits the buffer.

Comment: @HansPassant: please post as an answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Standard deadlock. Read the output first and then wait for exit. The
>   program cannot exit until you've read all of its output. The code you
>   have can only work if there's little output that fits the buffer.

From Hans Passant's comment